# Why is my React Component always showing the same state?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to use React and React Router to pass variables down to my RPGCompoent.

In this example, I am trying to pass a `gameId`.

So when I click each link, I should get one of these depending on which link(route):

```
game1 or game2 or game3
```

But when I click a link(route), it doesn't matter which one, I always just see this in the console output.  * (this the browser console):

```
gameIdState:  {gameId: "game1"}
```

Here is my main React app:

```
import React from 'react';
import RPGComponent from './RPGComponent';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function GamerTime() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/game_1">Game: Death Nights</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/game_2">Game: Army Medic</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/game_3">Game: Zombie Runner</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/game_1"
            render={() => <RPGComponent gameId="game1" />}
          />
          <Route path="/game_2"
            render={() => <RPGComponent gameId="game2" />}
          />
          <Route path="/game_3"
            render={() => <RPGComponent gameId="game3" />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Here is my RPGComponent:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const RPGComponent = (gameId) => {

    const [gameIdState, setGameIdState] = useState(gameId);

    console.log("gameIdState: ", gameIdState);

}

export default RPGComponent;
```

Comment: What else did you expect to see? Your `RPGComponent` doesn't render anything.

Comment: I mean the console in the browser.  I removed all the other code from the RPGComponent for this question because it just has to do with the variable `gameId` I am trying to pass into it. For some reason I can't figure out, gameIdState is always the set at "game1" even though the different routes are passing different values.

Comment: You can see my answer :) it should help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a hook for that if you pass gameId as a prop, you can just make it like this:

```
const RPGComponent = (props) => {
  console.log("gameIdState: ", props.gameId);

  return <div>test</div>;
};
```

Second thing - you don't render anything in `RPGComponent`. I created working example for you - [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-zz6gg?file=/index.js:998-1107) . So now when you click on the link it will show a div with test text inside it but in the console you will see actual gameId.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, gameId is fetched from props.

The parameter given to **useState** is much similar as setting state in **constructor** for a class component and isn't used to update the state on re-render.
You can use **useEffect** to update state

```
const RPGComponent = (props) => {
  const { gameId } = props;
  const [gameIdState, setGameIdState] = useState(gameId);
  useEffect(() => {
    setGameIdState(gameId);
  }, [gameId]);
  console.log('gameIdState: ', gameIdState);
  return (
    <div>
      {gameIdState}
      {gameId}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I like this hook approach but I noticed that it only really worked well on the first click.  On the second and third clicks I'd see the state for all routes. Like the first click, I'd see game1, but the second click I'd see game1 and game2.  Then the 3rd click I'd see all 3: game1, game2, and game3.